How to Clean Up the .NET Application workspace using Jenkinsfile?
I’m encountering an issue while attempting to clean the workspace folder for our .NET application through our Jenkinsfile. The CI/CD pipeline is set up to deploy to an IIS server, and each new build triggers automatically upon commits to GitHub. However, I've observed that certain DLL files remain locked on the IIS server side, preventing a full clearance of the workspace folder during the build process.
Due to these locked files, I’m unable to fully clean the workspace folder, which is causing the final build to fail. Here’s a summary of my configuration:
CI/CD Pipeline: Configured using Jenkinsfile to automatically build and deploy on every GitHub push.
Target Server: IIS, where certain DLL files are locked during deployment, hindering the clean-up process.
Issue Encountered: Incomplete clearance of the workspace folder due to locked files, resulting in build failure.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to effectively clear the workspace in this scenario, or any alternative approach to manage DLL lock issues during deployment.
I need some guidence for this issue.

Can you share what is the error you are facing? Maybe you can mark the DLL as lockable resources.
